# C# synchronous process starting

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm attempting to start a process from a piece of code but I want the code to pause execution until the process finishes and exits.  Currently I'm using the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() class to start (specifically) an uninstaller program, and the code executing afterwards does rely on the installer uninstaller finishing before it resumes execution.

Here's the code.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var procStIfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + variableContainingUninstallerPath);
procStIfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStIfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStIfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStIfo;
proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After your Start() call, add:

```
proc.WaitForExit();
```

See [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx) for details.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it is still applicable in 2021. So I want to point out an important nuance to using Mr. Copsey's answer: The started process may activate an existing instance of itself and pass the execution to that existing process, and then return as if it is completed, but in reality it is not. I ran into this when using Process.Start with PDF files. Adobe Reader will open the PDF in an existing instance (if available) and then WaitForExit will fire as if the process is complete, even thought the PDF is still open. This nuance made WaitForExit() unusable for my purposes.