# I write a code and I have 2 actions and I want to run 1 first, finish the process and start the second

Tags: c#

I write a code and I have 2 actions and I want to run one of them first, let the process finish and then start the second and finish the process. Somehow like that

```
    DoTheStuff(url);
    DoTheStuff(url1);
```

and this is the reference of url and url1:

```
  const string url = "http://example.org/download"; (example
  const string url1 = "http://example.org/download2";
```

and the reference of DoTheStuff is :

```
   private void DoTheStuff(string downloadURL)
{
    //Download File
    var fileName = DownloadToFileAutoName(downloadURL);
```

What I want to do is first

```
    const string url = "http://gooogle.com/download";
```

to DoTheStuff and after he finish the process to go to seccond

```
    const string url1 = "http://google.com/download2";
```

and DoTheStuff, understand

I forgot to mention when the first link is downloaded it must going to make autoinstall. This is the action of `DoTheStuff`, and after first download finish the autoinstall I need to pass to second link and `DoTheStuff`

Comment: I don't understand with which part you have a problem.

Comment: is making in visual studio this source code, i need somebody to help me with a simple comand to return or something like that

Comment: You do know that C# is sequential? It does all statements in sequence, and doesn't do the next statement until the current is finished. That means that the second function call will not happen until the first one is done.

Comment: but the first is going done, but the second doesn`t start

Comment: Have you tried running your code using a debugger? Probably there is something that blocks your program inside the first _DoTheStuff_

Comment: i do that but everithing is fine, but is not start the second job, i dont understand why. my skype is nightelf403 please add me to send u my team viewer info to see all source code and hope to help me

Comment: Post your full DoTheStuff, please, along with the rest of relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the installation as a synchronous process. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626094/c-sharp-synchronous-process-starting).
The key is to hold the process object and wait for it to finish by calling:

```
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: and there is proc.WaitForExit(DoTheStuff (url));

Comment: No. You normally don't need this. As mentioned above, your code will be executed synchronously and sequentially. Please post some real code so that we understand what it is about.

Comment: please add me on skype nightelf403 there i send u my teamviewer id and password to see all source code

Comment: and i write pro.WaitForExit(); but nothing